# Java Data Structures with Redis

Tags: java, string, data-structures, redis, hashmap

In my code I have declared this data structure below:

`LinkedHashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> GroupsOfaSignature = new LinkedHashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>();`

I want to save it in redis which has its own types of data structures(Strings,hash,...) .In the redis documentation they said that we can store hashmap Where the key and the values are Strings so my question is if i can store a hashmap where the keys or values are not strings,for example a linkedhashMap like the example above

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert them as strings. You can either use some Json libraries like gson to give you the equivalent Json string or you can use message pack to achieve the same.

http://msgpack.org/index.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert them to String though you can also store bitmaps . I would say when you have to store such a a representation either prefix key with some unique identifier for all the internal maps or use Json representation

You can also think of a Redis hash as a JSON object (with non-nestable objects).

```
Key: "usernameToUidMapping:a"
Value: "alpha" => "1"
       "adam" => "312"
       "acrobat" => "333"
       "aromatic" => "664"
```

Refer below link
[Redis Data Types](https://matt.sh/introduction-to-redis-data-types)